# How to specify type parameters in typescript declaration?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created a React component that takes a class of its child component. This component is responsible for providing the user ability to login via the OIDC protocol and if the user is logged in – rendering the child passing the user object as a prop (the child would use it in API calls).

This is how my component is declared:

```
type AuthProps = {
  childClass: typeof React.Component;
}

type AuthState = {
  user: Maybe<User>
}

class Auth extends React.Component<AuthProps, AuthState> {
}
```

Then I render my child element like:

```
<this.props.childClass user={this.state.user} />
```

This configuration works just fine. But what if I wanted more type safety? Namely if I want to ensure that `childClass` supports the `user` prop? I tried to type it like:

```
  childClass: typeof ReactComponent<{user: Maybe<User>}>,
```

this, however is not even a proper syntax. Is it possible to narrow the type of `childClass` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative 1:** `React.ComponentType`

```
type AuthProps = {
  childClass: React.ComponentType<{ user: Maybe<User> }>;
};

class Auth extends React.Component<AuthProps, AuthState> {
  render() {
    return <this.props.childClass user={this.state.user} />;
  }
}
```

`React.ComponentType` is a built-in type (replaces your `typeof React.Component`) and allows both class or function components to be used.

**Alernative 2:** [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

```
type AuthProps2 = {
  childClass: (user: Maybe<User>) => JSX.Element;
};

class Auth2 extends React.Component<AuthProps2, AuthState> {
  render() {
    return this.props.childClass(this.state.user);
  }
}
```

This is the preferred and safer alternative. Given the client passed an inline component like

```
const App = () => <Auth childClass={props => <div>{props.user}</div>} />;
```

, it prevents performance penalties of the first solution. Alternative 1 would remount the component in every render cycle, as the component instance changes each time (look [here](https://medium.com/@jacobdfriedmann/render-props-composability-and-performance-74dd4ac881e2) for a related article).